# How do I add a column and change this column to a dummy variable?

Tags: r

I have trouble generating the following dummy-variables in R, the following is the data,

```
    city           
1   A          
2   A           
3   A           
4   B          
5   B          
6   B          
7   C           
8   C           
9   C
```

then I want to add a new column for the data, the eastern city:A and C, the western city:B

```
    city     region
1   A         east
2   A         east
3   A         east   
4   B         west 
5   B         west
6   B         west 
7   C         east  
8   C         east
9   C         east
```

and change the region variable to dummy variable

```
    city     region
1   A         1
2   A         1
3   A         1   
4   B         0 
5   B         0
6   B         0 
7   C         1  
8   C         1
9   C         1
```

How do I do this by a simple command? Many thanks.

Comment: Gonna need a little more context here.  What constitutes east and west?

Answer (score 4):

Unsure of the purpose of your exercise. Anyhow, another option in case you need to have two-way transformation.  There are different ways to do it.  As a reference though.

```
# the data
df <- structure(list(city = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor")), .Names = "city", class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"))

# the operation
df$region <- with(df, ifelse(city %in% c("A","C"), "east", "west"))
df$region <- with(df, ifelse(region == "east", 1, 0))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do:

```
indx <- df$city %in% c('A', 'C')
df$region <- indx +0
df$region
#[1] 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1


df$region1 <- c('west', 'east')[indx+1]
df$region1
#[1] "east" "east" "east" "west" "west" "west" "east" "east" "east"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this to add a column:

```
my.dataframe$region <- a.vector
```

Edit:

First you could set everything to east:

```
x$region <- rep("east")
```

Then switch over the one city to west:

```
x$region <- ifelse(x$city == "B", "west", "east")
```

Comment: thx, so I must type all the region by myself? Do you have some method, such as I select city A and add the region value: east, and select the city B and add the region value:west, and so on.